# why does the HTML symbol for ▶ not work in document.title

Tags: javascript

I tried using `&#9658;` while setting `document.title` but it did not render the play symbol, just showed those same characters.

I'm able to paste  ▶  directly into the code, which works. I'm just curious why the first way wouldn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect the browser to interpret those symbols any different than normal text?

Comment: @jahroy: If you're not careful with character encodings, a lot of things can go wrong.

Comment: Rehashing for visibility, You should use [`'\U25B6'`](http://codepoints.net/U+25B6) in JS (instead of `...BA`) to get the symbol (▶) to appear more consistently in the page and browser title.  See my SO [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19353423/1366033) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Tt48M/10/show/light/) for more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16930921/201952) is correct in that a HTML document's title is plain text and cannot contain markup.

However, to be clear, you *can* use `&#9658;` in the HTML source (ie, `<title>&#9658;</title>`).  The *parser* will convert the entity in to the proper character in the string that gets stored in the DOM.

You're running in to an issue when you set `document.title`.  The HTML parser does not apply to JavaScript, even if the script is inline in a HTML document.  Your script simply sets the document's plain text title to the literal ampersand-pound-9658-semicolon because that sequence of characters has no special meaning in script.

If you want to escape a character in script source, use a JavaScript [escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode_escape_sequences).  Unicode escape sequences in JavaScript require the hex representation of the Unicode code point, and your entity is using the decimal representation (9568).  Convert to hex and we get 25BA:

```
document.title = '\u25ba Playing';
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I am noticing that the symbol is actually **different**, is this supposed to be? it seems shorter (smaller height) than using the symbol itself...

Comment: That would be because the title is displayed outside the context of the browser HTML and is using a different font.

Comment: @d-_-b, I had the same issue.  YouTube seems to use the unicode character [**`U+25B6`**](http://codepoints.net/U+25B6) for better results.  See my SO Q/A [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19353423/1366033) or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Tt48M/2/show/light/)

Answer (score 8):

`&#9658;` is an HTML entity reference, but `document.title` does not contain HTML; it contains plain text. For example, if I set `document.title` to `<strong>Hello</strong> <em>world</em>`, it would display that literally, rather than showing **Hello** *world*. The same goes for any other piece of HTML, including entity references.

To be clear, you *can* include entity references in a `title` tag. They will be interpreted when the page is parsed. However, `document.title` accesses the text after it has been parsed and all entities substituted. `document.title` will access the *text* of the `title` tag, not the HTML inside of it that was originally used to create it. Similarly, setting `document.title` does not make any HTML inside of it be automatically interpreted.

Including the character literally can cause issues if the browser for some reason interprets your page in a different character encoding than it's actually in. HTML entities protect against this in HTML, but there's also a way to escape them in JavaScript. In particular, you can include ► in JavaScript with the string escape `\u25ba`. (9658<sub>10</sub> converted to base 16 is 26BA<sub>16</sub>)

Comment: @d-_-b: In short, because it's just another character. JavaScript uses Unicode, which defines a large set of characters, including not only characters like `a`, `1`, `@`, and `あ`, but also other symbols you might want to occur in text, like `▶`. These symbols do not require any special support from HTML; HTML entities are there to make things easier to type (and also to prevent encoding issues). You could even encode `a` as an entity if you wanted to like `&#97;`.

Comment: It's "allowed" if it's part of the charset you're using (ie. UTF-8 etc). If a different charset it might show up as another symbol as the char itself is just a numeric representation internally.

Comment: Sorry, crash-post. Don't confuse Javascript (UTF-16) with HTML (which can encode differently) btw.

Comment: wow, this answer sure has expanded since when i first upvoted hahah