# Play symbol (▶) squished in document.title

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Adding to the question on [Why does the HTML symbol for ▶ not work in document.title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930905/why-does-the-html-symbol-for-not-work-in-document-title),
when I add the play symbol to the document title using the properly escaped javascript hex value, the symbol seems squished:

**JavaScript:**

```js
document.title = '\u25BA' + document.title;
```

**Inside Page** *(correct)*

[image: BodyDemo]

**Inside Title** *(not so correct)*

[image: TitleDemo]

See this fiddle for a working model.  I've added *`/show/light`* so the javascript can actually access the document title on the main page, but if you take off the extension, you can see the code as well.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Tt48M/show/light/)

This appears to be happening on all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE).

**Tested** (on Win8) in:

- Chrome: *version 30.0*
- Firefox: *version 22.0*
- IE: *version 10.0*

When I go to YouTube, it looks fine, so I'm not positive it's a Browser Specific Issue.

[image: YouTubeDemo]

Comment: Maybe because the font is based on the OS/Browser? It seems to be displaying fine on Chromium+Ubuntu. Can you include the OS/Browser so we can check accordingly?

Comment: I've noticed the effect in Firefox with YouTube.com on Windows. I've assumed it was an OS font issue and beyond the scope of anything that you could control in CSS or JavaScript

Comment: If nothing else works properly throughout all environments, you could probably try changing the favicon dynamically instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Pasting the symbol that YouTube uses (▶) into [codepoints.net](http://codepoints.net/), you can see that they are actually using a different unicode version.  The character returned is [**`U+25B6`**](http://codepoints.net/U+25B6) (not to be confused with `25B8` and `25BA`)

This should look better:

```js
function PrependPageTitle(player) {
    var playIcon = '\u25B6 ';
    var startsWithIcon = document.title.substring(0, playIcon.length)===playIcon;

    if (player.paused && startsWithIcon) {
        document.title = document.title.slice(playIcon.length);
    } else if (!player.paused && !startsWithIcon) {
        document.title = playIcon + document.title;
    }
}
```

Demo Here:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Tt48M/10/show/light/)