# How to use encoded HTML text within string literals?

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I am trying to include a HTML encoded special character within a string literal, but it will not render as HTML in the final document.

I am trying to do it like such:

```
const head = { 
title: `${ApplicationName} - ${Slogan}&trade;`
}
```

In the above code the `&trade;` part it supposed to render a trademark symbol like ™. But when this code makes it into the HTML document it ends up rendering as a string:

```
<head>
  <title>Imaginary Inc - We straight don't exist&trade;</title>
</head>
```

Is there any way to get it to work, maybe using some kind of escaping technique?

Comment: How is the HTML generated? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please show how the text is inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why does the HTML symbol for ▶ not work in document.title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930905/why-does-the-html-symbol-for-not-work-in-document-title)

Comment: Good argument. It tells you exactly why the entity is not working for the `title` element and what you can do instead.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok yes it makes sense after seeing Skully's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unicode of the character to achieve this, add a backslash before the character unicode to denote this in JavaScript. (`™` → `\u2112`)

```js
const title = $("title");
title.append("\u2122");

console.log(title.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
</head>
```

Comment: That worked great, except all I needed to do was ``title: `${ApplicationName} - ${Slogan}\u2112``

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML or a DOM Parser with innerText

```js
let t = document.querySelector('title');
let var1 = 'foo', var2 = 'bar'
let str = `${var1} - ${var2}&trade;`
t.innerHTML = str;
console.log(t)

let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
t.innerText = doc.body.innerHTML;
console.log(t)
```

```html
<title></title>
```